# Asp net core + postgresql + gitlab ci + heroku

Tags: c#, postgresql, heroku, gitlab-ci

я новичок в docker, gitlab ci, обыскал весь интернет и не сомг найти пример использования, может ли кто-то дать какой-то пример?

Comment: А примеры использования того что между плюсиками, нашли?